# How can i create custome keyboard in telegram bot with c#?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I'm new in telegram bot, and want to create the custom keyboard for my bot, for that purpose write this code:

```
var rkm = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();

rkm.Keyboard =
    new KeyboardButton[][]
    {
        new KeyboardButton[]
        {
            new KeyboardButton("1-1"),
            new KeyboardButton("1-2")
        },

        new KeyboardButton[]
        {
            new KeyboardButton("2")
        },
        new KeyboardButton[]
        {
            new KeyboardButton("3-1"),
            new KeyboardButton("3-2"),
            new KeyboardButton("3-3")
        }
    };

WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + "282189232:AAGdsdsdsdVOrsxy2rzU75QUAnWL_F2vo" + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&text=" + message + "&reply_markup=" + rkm);
req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
var result = req.GetResponse();
req.Abort();
```

but when i run that code in this line:

```
var result = req.GetResponse();
```

get this error:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: you can use an already exists SDK for communicating with Telegram bot, here is a great SDK for doing that https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot

Answer (score 0):

As suggested use the library by MrRoundRobin. here is how you would do it:

```
var keyboard = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(new [] {
    new [] // 1st row
    {
        new KeyboardButton("1"),
        new KeyboardButton("2"),
    },
    new [] // 2nd row
    {
        new KeyboardButton("3"),
        new KeyboardButton("4"),
    }
});

await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "Choose", replyMarkup: keyboard);;
```